# Codename One fading scrollbar

Tags: containers, codenameone

I am using a container with a scrollbar like this:

```
containerNumbers.setScrollableX(true);
containerNumbers.setScrollVisible(true);
```

In addition, I have set the theme constants:

```
fadeScrollBarBool  = false
fadeScrollEdgeBool = false
```

Still the scrollbar continues fading and I can see no indicator edges. The scrollbar is at the bottom, where it is very narrow and almost invisible.

I would like to have a somewhat wider scrollbar that is easily perceivable.

I have  seen a tutorial [here](http://codenameone.blogspot.com.br/2008/07/pimp-my-lwuit-part-iii-scrollbar-part.html) , but it seems a little dificult to achieve.

Is there any easy approach to set the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is super old and you shouldn't refer to it as a guide.

Make sure the theme constant was set correctly by invoking in your `init(Object)` method:

```
UIManager().getLookAndFeel().setFadeScrollBar(false);
```

Comment: Shai, UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setFadeScrollBar(false) worked perfectly. I have tried doing the same with the scroll edges         UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setFadeScrollEdge(false), but I cannot see any of them. And: is there any way to increase the width of the scrollbar?

Comment: Edges don't mean that. They mean the edge fades out which was common on some OS's. I think that what you are looking for are scrollbar arrows which don't exist in Codename One by default. If you want a desktop style scrollbar check out this post https://www.codenameone.com/blog/permanent-sidemenu-getAllStyles-scrollbar-and-more.html